# Express that all tangent lines to a curve are parallel

Tags: differential-geometry, curves

I am wondering if I can express in a formal way the fact that all tangent lines to a curve are parallel in the following way:

$$\alpha(s)+\lambda(s)\alpha'(s)=k$$ where $\alpha$ is the curve and $k$ is a constant.

It would be correct to express the family of lines like this? I know it is a simple doubt but I am getting confused with the notation in my book, so I need to be sure. Thanks.

Comment: Could you draw or plot a figure?  As it stands this makes no sense that I can see.

Comment: I am puzzled that you WANT to "express" something that is NOT true!  Or is it your intention to prove that any curve for which this is true must be a straight  line?

Comment: Yes, @GeorgeIvey,that was my final aim´

Comment: This is fine. Of course, you can without loss of generality assume $k=0$.

Comment: Regarding your final aim: If the curve is assumed regular, the tangent at $s,t \in I$ are parallel if and only if $\frac{\alpha'(s)}{\|\alpha'(s)\|} = \pm\frac{\alpha'(t)}{\|\alpha'(t)\|}$. If you assume this holds for all $s,t$, then the sign must be $+$ by continuity. Can you go on from there?

Comment: Another equivalent way of expressing this would be that all tangent lines must pass through a fixed point, right?